Finding a limit using Taylor expansion
I am trying to solve the following exercise:
Given $f(0)=f''(0)=1, f'(0)=0$, find the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}))^n$$
My thoughts:
As we're dealing with a sequence, of course we're gonna use Heine's theorem for this.
Define a function $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$, and write $f$ as Taylor polynomial of order 2 at 0, plus remiander:
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + R_2(x)=1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+R_2(x)$$
Substituting the function we defined, raising to the power of $x$, and taking the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{2x}+R_2(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}))^x$$
Now, we want to get to the form of the known $e$ limit. Getting common denominator, and then raising to the power of $\frac{2}{2}$ in order to get the same in the denominator and the power:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}((1+\frac{1+2xR_2(\frac{1}{\sqrt x})}{2x})^{2x})^\frac{1}{2}$$
We get:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{(1+2xR_2(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}))\cdot\frac{1}{2}}$$
Then, I want to use "second Taylor's theorem" (that's what our lecturer calls it) in order to say that the remainder approaches 0, and then i'll get the answer: $e^\frac{1}{2}$. But I have this annoying $x$ next to $R_2(x)$, and it's a situation of "$\infty\cdot 0$".
How do I move on from here?

We have $f(x)=1+(\frac{1}{2}+R_{2}(x))x^{2}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}R_{2}(x)=0$ (I chose the Wikipedia version); the first condition gives $f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})=1+\left(\frac{1}{2}+R_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\right)\frac{1}{n}$. For the second one we use the definition of a (right) limit of $R_{2}$ in $0$;$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x\in dom(R_{2})\cap(0,\delta):|R_{2}(x)|<\epsilon\textrm{.}$$Taking $m:=(Ent(\frac{1}{\delta})+1)^2$ (such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ is in $(0,\delta)$) we obtain$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists m\in\mathbb{N},\forall n>m,n\in\mathbb{N}:|R_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})|<\epsilon\textrm{;}$$the convergence of $R_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ to zero. Finally,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{\left[1+\frac{1}{n/\left(\frac{1}{2}+R_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\right)}\right]^{\frac{n}{\frac{1}{2}+R_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})}}\right\}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}+R_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\right)}=e^{1/2}$$

Hint
$$f(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+x^2\epsilon(x)$$
With $\lim_0\epsilon=0$.
$$\ln(f(x))=\frac{x^2}{2}+x^2\epsilon(x)$$
$$x^2\ln(f(\frac 1x))=\frac 12+\epsilon(x)$$
Use
$$\displaystyle{(f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}))^n=e^{n\ln(f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) )}}$$

I hope my account will not be suspended.

I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your steps. For example, if you took $ln$ of $f$, why didn't you do it on the right hand side as well?

@natitati $\ln(1+X)=X+X\epsilon(X)$
